# xcode/ios: trying to copy files to caches folder on install

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm trying to copy a bunch of files to my app's caches folder when the app is installed on the device. I tried to use the `Copy Files phase` to achieve this, but i don't really know which path to use for its destination.

[image: screenshot xcode 4.2.1]

is this the right approach ... ?
or is this not possible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if it is impossible using this approach. However you can always write a method which preloads your resources on launch to Caches dir. Here's sample code:

```
NSString* path=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
path=[path stringByAppendingString:@"/plpart1.txt"];
NSError* error;
NSString* source=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pl_part1" ofType:@"txt"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:source toPath:path error:&error];
```