# copying Realm file in Caches Directory

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store, realm, xcode7.3

My app got rejected by Apple because of this : "On launch and content download, your app stores 13.01 MB on the user's iCloud, which does not comply with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines."

I know what's the problem.how can i save my Realm database in Caches Directory instead of Documents directory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489342/xcode-ios-trying-to-copy-files-to-caches-folder-on-install

Comment: this is not what i want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Realm.Configuration.fileURL` to change a Realm file path. Like the following:

```
let cachesDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.CachesDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
let cachesDirectoryURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: cachesDirectoryPath)
let fileURL = cachesDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Default.realm")

let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: fileURL)
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

If you would not like to specify `fileURL` every instantiating Realm, you can use `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration`. If you set a configuration object to  `defaultConfiguration`, `Realm()` uses the configuration as default.

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
let realm = Realm()
```

See also... https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realm-configuration

Answer (score 0):

I updated kishikawa's answer for **Swift 5** and **Realm 10**.
I call this func in AppDelegate's "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions":

```
private func setRealmDefaultConfig() {
    let cachesDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let cachesDirectoryURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: cachesDirectoryPath)
    let fileURL = cachesDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("Default.realm")
    let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: fileURL)
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
}
```

keep in mind that obviously "DefaultConfiguration" will be used only when instantiating with no new config: `Realm()`